# Swift Grand Central Dispatch Queues and UIImages

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I know this type of question has been asked 1e7 times but I have come across a specific issue that I don't think has been covered/is blatantly obvious but I am too novice to fix it on my own.

I have the following code snippet within my `cellForRowAt` method in a `TableViewController`:

```
let currentDictionary = parser.parsedData[indexPath.row] as Dictionary<String,String>

let urlString = currentDictionary["media:content"]

if urlString != nil {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url! as URL) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
```

Which executes fine, downloads the images and assigns them to the `UIImageView` of each `tableViewCell`.

There is a finite delay when scrolling the table as the images are downloaded 'on the fly' so to speak.

What I want to do is pre-download all these images and save them in a data structure so they are fetched from URL's less frequently.

I have tried the following implementation:

```
var thumbnail = UIImage()

for item in parser.parsedData {
    let currentDictionary = item as Dictionary<String,String>
    let title = currentDictionary["title"]
    let link = currentDictionary["link"]
    let urlString = currentDictionary["media:content"]
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)


    if urlString != nil {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url! as URL)
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                thumbnail = UIImage(data: data!)!
            }
        }
    }

    var newsArticle: News!
    newsArticle = News(title: title!, link: link!, thumbnail: thumbnail)

    news.append(newsArticle)
```

Where news is my data structure. This code also executes fine, however each thumbnail is a 0x0 sized image,  size {0, 0} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, according to the console output.

Does anyone have any ideas how to download these images but not immediately assign them to a `UIImageView`, rather store them for later use?

Comment: This is quite a wide question - instead of directly answering, I would recommend you to take an existing library for handling images, and use that instead. They usually have a way for asynchronous setting of images based on URL, and also have a way of prefetching images (without having to store them manually). I use Kingfisher ( https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher ), but another popular one is SDWebImage ( https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage ).

Comment: If for some reason it is required that you don't use a third party library, take a look into `URLCache` ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcache ) in combination with `URLSession` (I've been using that also), or otherwise you'll have to implement your own cache. Anyway, unless really necessary, I would really try to go with Kingfisher, or SDWebImage library.

Comment: Use SDWebCache Library

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create your `newsArticle` before the global dispatch queue even started to process your `url`. Therefore, `thumbnail` is still the empty `UIImage()` created in the very first line.

You'll have to create the thumbnail inside the inner dispatch closure, like:

```
for item in parser.parsedData {
    guard let currentDictionary = item as? Dictionary<String,String>    else { continue /* or some error handling */ }
    guard let title = currentDictionary["title"]                        else { continue /* or some error handling */ }
    guard let link = currentDictionary["link"]                          else { continue /* or some error handling */ }
    guard let urlString = currentDictionary["media:content"]            else { continue /* or some error handling */ }
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString)                              else { continue /* or some error handling */ }

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                if let thumbnail = UIImage(data: data) {
                    let newsArticle = News(title: title, link: link, thumbnail: thumbnail)

                    news.append(newsArticle)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

By the way, your very first code (`cellForRow...`) is also broken: You must not reference the cell inside the dispatch closure:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Never do this
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

Instead, reference the `IndexPath`, retrieve the cell inside the clousure, and go on with that cell. But as you already mentioned, there are many many entries on stackoverflow regarding this issue.

Comment: @Moritz you are right, that was just copy&paste from above. There are much more things to improve, but I just focussed on the one problem with the _empty_ (and non-`nil`) thumbnail. But I just improved it...